# Event flags in jQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm hoping to add events to some Google Flot charts, like those seen in Google Finance. After searching some, it looks like someone has started this and has posted a couple images at http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage. I can't find any Flot plugins that can do this.

Does anyone know of a Flot plugin or example so I can make sure not to re-invent any wheels?

Comment: I don't understand, the link you posted is a plugin for jQuery, what plugin are you actually looking for?

Comment: Flot is hosting on code.google.com, but this isn't something that is produced by Google. A more appropriate name might be "jQuery Flot".

Comment: Thanks, Jon. For some reason I had Google on the brain. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current release (0.5) can't do this, but if you pull the latest version from "trunk" it can. Just look for something called "markings" in the API doc:
http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/API.txt

I use the markings feature to draw a vertical line on a day when something happened. For example, you could draw vertical lines on the days you shipped a new piece of software on a chart that contains website traffic metrics.

Comment: I was just wondering how I could add markers for specific days in my chart. I had decided on simply ploting them as [date, chartmax] so it would plot a vertical line and I could tag it by using the legend.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [plugin](http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/flot-plugins-event-graphics/) that adds advanced event support. You may want to check it out (although this was a fair while ago :-P)

Comment: Cool. Your plugin seems to be a little more robust than what I ended up doing, which was tweaking the markers functionality.